# MySQL group by URL path pattern

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

How to group rows with URLs by path pattern? E.g. we have there addresses:

```
1  http://example.com
2  http://example.com/products
3  http://example.com/products/some-product
4  http://example.com/categories
5  http://example.com/categories/cat1
6  http://example.com/categories/cat2
7  http://example.com/categories/cat3
8  http://example.com/tags
9  http://example.com/tags/tag1
10 http://example.com/tags/tag2
11 http://example.com/tags/tag3
12 http://example.com/about
```

So results would be:

```
1  http://example.com
2  http://example.com/products
3  http://example.com/products/some-product
4  http://example.com/categories
5  http://example.com/categories/cat1
8  http://example.com/tags
9  http://example.com/tags/tag1
12 http://example.com/about
```

We know domain http://example.com. We need all distinct path types. Basically we want to know what different pages website have. So it's kind of http://example.com/ * / * / * ...

Comment: You need to describe the logic behind the grouping. 1) How do you determine which values should be grouped together 2) From the similar ones which one to keep.

Comment: 1) added comment in the bottom. 2) We take first one.

Comment: In an rdbms there is no such thing as a first one. You need to determine first by what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

[Rextester Sample](http://rextester.com/ZBUAC95003)

```
select * from tbl1 t1
where exists
(select 1
from tbl1 t2
  group by substring_index(concat(url,'@'),'/',4)
having t1.id=min(t2.id)
);
```

In `MYSQL`, there is no hard rule for not selecting columns which are not in `group by`. So you can go by this as well.

```
select *
from tbl1
group by 
    substring_index(concat(url,'@'),'/',4) 
order by id
;
```

> Role of `substring_index(concat(url,'@'),'/',4)`

It will first add an extra character at the end of the url, say `@`. Then it would truncate the `url` till the `4th` `/`. Without adding `@` at the end, `http://example.com/categories/cat1` and `http://example.com/categories` will be put in same `group` which you dont want.

Comment: Thanks! That works. Maybe you could tell how to drop/ignore everything after ? or # in urls? :)

Comment: Changed the query which would work in almost all RDBMS, To drop everything after(including) a particular character say `?`, use `substring_index(url,'?',1)`. Read a bit about `substring_index`, very useful function.